# Authorization fingerprint example

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

Whether you can authenticate to an application using fingerprint?
If, yes.
Can it someone show you an example.
To the application must be logged password or fingerprint.
The fingerprint will be stored locally.

Comment: I mean android system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fingerprint api **will be released in Android M**.

Before this version, there is no official support of it.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has its own API.

Here is the link to the library

http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#pass